# How to sum values of a queryset in the view.py

Tags: django, templates, filter, view, sum

This is my view.py:

```
class PaymentControlList(ListView):
    template_name = "any.html"
    model = Payment

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = PaymentFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())

        return context
```

In that model (Payment) I have a field called value, how can I create an variable called total and used it in my template?
That is my template.py

```
{% for item in filter.qs %}

    {% if item.entrada %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ item.data }}</th>
        <td>{{ item.payment }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
        <td class="item-value">{{ item.value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<h3> {{ total }} </h3> <!--Sum of item.value
```

Just to let you know I have written the filter using django-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do another query to sum the values and add it to the context:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class PaymentControlList(ListView):
    template_name = "any.html"
    model = Payment

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        filter = PaymentFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        context['filter'] = filter
        context['total'] = filter.qs.aggregate(Sum('value')).get('value__sum')

        return context
```

Comment: Ivan. many thx and I got your idea, but that total as you mentioned is a total of everything that is in the database I would like to know if it is possible to make a total of the data that is coming from the filter.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. By using [.qs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs) it should do what you want.